# NestJS -> Postgres got Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nestjs

I deploy my NestJS server to AWS ec2 using Ubuntu
Everything is so smooth but when I log my nestjs server. It threw this error:
`[Nest] 1  - 06/16/2023, 1:19:36 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN postgres at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)`
My docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  backend: 
    build: ./
    container_name: nestjs_api_karaoke_sp
    environment:
      - PORT=3001
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=postgres
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=1234
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432
      - DATABASE_NAME=KARAOKE_SONGPHUNG
      - DATABASE_HOST=postgres
    ports:
        - "3001:3001"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - nestjs_network

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=KARAOKE_SONGPHUNG
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - "./postgres-backup:/data/db"

networks:
  nestjs_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Anyone can help me solve this problem?
Thanks in advance